# I am getting stuck in embedding a video in a website from desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

These are my code snippets which I've tried but I just get an error message that I need a Plugin

```
<embed src="eria.mp4" height="50%" width="100%" controls>
```

Comment: The code wasn't properly formatted.

Comment: Use the video tag, if you want to add a MP4 video, and be sure all browsers can read your MP4 video (I'm not sure).
If you want to embed a video on your website, use some video player like video.js and follow the documentation.
http://videojs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any plugin in HTML5. But the syntax is a bit different:

```
<video width="100%" height="50%" controls>
    <source src="eria.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<embed>` tag defines a container for an external application or interactive content (a plug-in).Simple words it requires a plugin to run external application which is missing from your browser.

Use `HTML5` video tag instead

```
<video height="50%" width="100%" controls>
  <source src="eria.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="eria.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```